# Sending arguments to a function on DOM event

Tags: javascript, css, onfocus

I am trying to send an argument to a function call on javascript event.

On drop down menu receiving focus text changes somewhere depending on what argument is passed to the function call.

Unable to make this work! Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function changeText(x) {
  if (x) {
    document.querySelector('.focused').textContent = 'Focused';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.focused').textContent = 'LOST';
  }
}

document.querySelector('.selector').onfocus = changeText(true);
document.querySelector('.selector').onfocusout = changeText(false);
```

```html
<select class='selector'>
  <option value = 'one'>One</option>
  <option value = 'two'>Two</option>
</select>

<br />
<br />
<br />


<div class = 'focused'>XXX</div>
```

Comment: Bind might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:
I used anonymous functions to wrap your function.
I used addEventListener('focusin'/'focusout') since the "onfocusout" did not trigger when losing focus.

```js
function changeText(x) {
  if (x) {
    document.querySelector('.focused').textContent = 'Focused';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.focused').textContent = 'LOST';
  }
}

document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('focusin',function(){ changeText(true); });
document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('focusout',function(){ changeText(false); });
```

```html
<select class='selector'>
  <option value = 'one'>One</option>
  <option value = 'two'>Two</option>
</select>

<br />
<br />
<br />


<div class = 'focused'>XXX</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Javascript. How do you figure out where to use function without parenthesis and where to use with? Something that always throws me off.

Comment: Functions with parentheses are when the function is called, while without parentheses it is the function. The code you presented calls the function `changeText`, and assigns the return value to the event handler. This is not what you want, another way to fix it would be to return functions from `changeText`. There is also the function declaration, it has parentheses for the argument list, followed by a function body in braces.